# props.submit not working inside class but working outside in React

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I am applying some validation in a form in a different component. The buttons are in a separate component than the form. I have an issue when validating inside the class. Suppose SchoolSuplyPage.js is invoking the form and executing submit and touch for validation:

```
const steps = (props) => [
     {
     content: (
       <SupplyForm
         initialValues={props?.supplyList}
         onSubmit={handleSave}
       />
     ),
     button: [
       <React.Fragment key="supply-buttons">
          <Button
            onClick={async(e) => {
              props.submit('AddSuppliesForm'); //these lines work for validation successfully
              props.touch('AddSuppliesForm); // these lines work for validation successfully
              const response = handleSave(e,formValues);
              ...
            }}
          >
            Save
          </Button>
       </React.Fragment>
     ]
     }
];

export class SupplyPage extends Component {
   ...
   handleSave = (e, formValue) => {
     e.preventDefault();
     this.props.submit('AddSuppliesForm');//these lines not working for validation, but should work
     this.props.touch('AddSuppliesForm');//these lines not working for validation, but should work
     if (!this.props.formErrors){
       return this.handleCreateSupply(formValue);
     }
   }
   ...
   const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
      supply: getSupply(state) || {},
      formErrors: getFormSyncErrors('AddSuppliesForm')(state) || {},
      formValues: getFormValues('AddSupliesForm')(state) || {},
   });

   const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) =>({
        bindActionCreators(
        {
          submit,
          reset,
          touch,
          change,
          destroy,
        },
        dispatch
        ),
    });
   export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(SupplyPage)
  )
}
```

How could I conduct the validation inside the class SupplyPage in the handleSave? Somehow the validation is working in steps function, but not in handleSave. I suspect some binding is needed inside the class to make it work.

Thanks in advance.